# String Detected as Code

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why this isn't working! All the code is being detected as code and not a string to be inserted as it should be. This is supposed to be a mouse follower. Since it is for a chrome extension it is meant to only be js.
The only code that is not supposed to be a string is:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
```

and

```
script.appendChild(code);
document.body.appendChild(script);
var div = document.createElement("div");
var node = document.createTextNode("<img alt="pickle"   
src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rickandmorty/images/1/19/
Pickle_rick_transparent.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/363?
cb=20171025014216">");
div.style.visibility = "hidden";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.zIndex = "3";
div.appendChild(node);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");

var code = document.createTextNode("var firstevent = -1;
var supported = -1;
var xcurs=0;
var ycurs=0;

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5", 0) != -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 6", 0) != -1){
 supported = 1;}
if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" && parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 5){
 supported = 1;}
if (navigator.appName == "Konqueror" && parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 5){
 supported = 1;}

function updatePosition(e){
if(firstevent == -1 && supported != -1){
 document.getElementById("jack").style.visibility = "visible";
 firstevent = 1;};
if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape'){
 xcurs = e.pageX;
 ycurs = e.pageY;}
else{
 xcurs = event.clientX;
 ycurs = event.clientY;};
}
}

function showBat(){
if (supported != -1) {
 supported = 1;
 document.getElementById("jack").style.left = (xcurs+10) + "px";
 document.getElementById("jack").style.top = (ycurs+2) + "px";
};

myTimeout=setTimeout('showBat()',10);
return;
}

myTimeout=setTimeout('showBat()',10);
document.onmousemove=updatePosition;");
script.appendChild(code);
document.body.appendChild(script);
var div = document.createElement("div");
var node = document.createTextNode("<img alt="pickle" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rickandmorty/images/1/19/Pickle_rick_transparent.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/363?cb=20171025014216">");
div.style.visibility = "hidden";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.zIndex = "3";
div.appendChild(node);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you putting code in a string?

Comment: `var node = document.createTextNode("<img alt="pickle" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rickandmorty/images/1/19/Pickle_rick_transparent.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/363?cb=20171025014216">");` certainly is incorrect, look at the syntax highlighting for example.

Comment: The road to hell is paved with `eval();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval .  Bring snacks for the journey

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious: if you can run code in the context of an HTML document to insert a node (`script` or otherwise), you can run code in the context of an HTML document to do whatever else you want to do.

Comment: Quotes are missed up while creating `node`: `var node = document..createTextNode("<img alt="pickl...)`. Plus you can't have a single string on multiple lines (at least not like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the end function bracket for function updatePosition(e)

```
function updatePosition(e){
if(firstevent == -1 && supported != -1){
    document.getElementById("jack").style.visibility = "visible";
    firstevent = 1;};
if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape'){
    xcurs = e.pageX;
    ycurs = e.pageY;}
else{
    xcurs = event.clientX;
    ycurs = event.clientY;};
}
}
```